# Ignore existing data when adding foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have one table in DB that already have some data, this is table for example

```
public class Foo {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string FooTypeId {get; set;}
}
```

`FooTypeId` is not FK, I was just storing strings in it, for example 'TABLE', 'CHAIR'..

Now I want to make new table that will hold values for `FooType`, so `FooTypeId` becomes Foreign key.

So I made it like this:

```
public class Foo {
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public string FooTypeId {get; set; }
    public virtual FooType {get; set; }
}

public class FooType {
    public string Id {get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
}
```

That's okay. But, I have already existing data in `Foo` table ('chair', 'table',..), and I'm adding new data on startup. So it's crashing.

Question is:
How do I ignore existing data WITH Entity Framework in this case? Strictly with Entity Framework.

Comment: You [could disable foreign key checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/disable-foreign-key-constraints-with-insert-and-update-statements?view=sql-server-ver15) but that would be silly. If the data already in there doesn't represent a valid value, then why not move that data to a different column?

Comment: What exactly don you mean by "_ignore existing data_"? If you want to `ignore` the data in `FooTypeId`, then you have to ignore the column itself. But you have made `FooTypeId` now a foreign key column. So now you'll need the `Id` values of `FooType` in this column. Do you want to remove/delete those data? Please clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using migrations, you can edit the generated migration "UP" method. In this method you'll have some operations to create the foreign key in Foo. Probably a call to [MigrationBuilder.AddForeignKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder.addforeignkey?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Migrations_MigrationBuilder_AddForeignKey_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Migrations_ReferentialAction_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Migrations_ReferentialAction_). Before calling this method, you can use [MigrationBuilder.InsertData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder.insertdata?view=efcore-5.0) to insert values needed in FooType so the foreign key creation doesn't fail.

Something similar to this:

```
//Here should be code to create FooType table
modelBuilder.InsertData("FooType", {"Id", "Name"}, {"Varchar", "Varchar"}, {{ Id="T", Name="Table" }, { Id="C", Name="Chair" }}, "dbo");
migrationBuilderBuilder.AddForeignKey("FK_Foo_FooType", "Foo", "FooTypeId", "FooType", "dbo", "dbo", "Id", ReferentialAction.Cascade, ReferentialAction.Cascade);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't 'ignore' the existing data, you must allow for it.

1. Create all the rows in FooType (including any data that is referenced by Foo).
2. Perform the migration
3. Profit